# PostgreSQL Generated Column from a JSONB column with nested values

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb, generated-columns

I have following table with a JSONB column:

```sql
CREATE TABLE movies (
    contributors    JSONB
);
```

The data in the column looks like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO movies (contributors) VALUES('[
  {"last_name": "Robbins", "first_name": "Tim", "age": 61},
  {"last_name": "Freeman", "first_name": "Morgan", "age": 83}
]');
```

Now I want to add a generated column of vectors. It should only contain `last_name` of the JSONB column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE movies ADD COLUMN search TSVECTOR
    GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TO_TSVECTOR('simple',
        /* need help here  */
    )) STORED;
```

Can anyone help me out how to do that? Vectors should look like this `'freeman':2 'robbin':1` [Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9e3ce02877eaf96d1f8dab2541660b9e)

Comment: This would be way easier with a properly normalized data model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the [JSON Path expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH) you can specify the items in the JSON data. With following example only items with the key `last_name` will be included:

```sql
ALTER TABLE movies ADD COLUMN search TSVECTOR
    GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TO_TSVECTOR('simple',
        jsonb_path_query_array(contributors, '$[*].last_name') /* ✅ */
    )) STORED;
```

[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=91a6df0412937277339272c74e9567b7)

Thank you `RhodiumToad` in the #postgresql IRC channel for providing a solution for this problem ‍♂️